# How to display file size in netrw in a human readable way?

Tags: netrw

When using netrw, (by :Vex or :Sex), the files can be displayed in different ways by pressing "i". And there is a view that the sizes of the files are displayed. However, the sizes are in bytes. Is there any way to show the sizes in a human readable way? like "ls -sh" in shell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could try netrw v155e with its size-styling parameter:

```
let g:netrw_sizestyle= "h"
```

Get it from http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW

Answer (score 3):

For local file system listings, the netrw plugin uses Vim's `getfsize()` function. Its value would need to be converted to human units. Luckily, my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433) provides such a function, so the following patch extends netrw (of the latest alpha version v154a from [here](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#NETRW)) in such way:

```
--- netrw.vim.orig  2015-04-10 20:45:06.094760300 +0200
+++ netrw.vim   2015-04-10 20:47:38.387988100 +0200
@@ -9934,7 +9934,7 @@ fun! s:LocalListing()
"   call Decho("pfile   <".pfile.">")

    if w:netrw_liststyle == s:LONGLIST
-    let sz   = getfsize(filename)
+    let sz   = join(ingo#units#FormatBytesBinary(getfsize(filename)))
    let fsz  = strpart("               ",1,15-strlen(sz)).sz
    let pfile= pfile."\t".fsz." ".strftime(g:netrw_timefmt,getftime(filename))
"    call Decho("sz=".sz." fsz=".fsz)
```

If you also want relative file modification dates (e.g. *5 minutes ago*) via a new option value `g:netrw_timefmt = 'relative'`, you can apply the following patch instead:

```
--- netrw.vim.orig  2015-04-10 20:45:06.094760300 +0200
+++ netrw.vim   2015-04-10 20:55:40.937242900 +0200
@@ -9934,9 +9934,9 @@ fun! s:LocalListing()
"   call Decho("pfile   <".pfile.">")

    if w:netrw_liststyle == s:LONGLIST
-    let sz   = getfsize(filename)
+    let sz   = join(ingo#units#FormatBytesBinary(getfsize(filename)))
    let fsz  = strpart("               ",1,15-strlen(sz)).sz
-    let pfile= pfile."\t".fsz." ".strftime(g:netrw_timefmt,getftime(filename))
+    let pfile= pfile."\t".fsz."  ".(g:netrw_timefmt ==# 'relative' ? ingo#date#HumanReltime(localtime() - getftime(filename)) : strftime(g:netrw_timefmt,getftime(filename)))
"    call Decho("sz=".sz." fsz=".fsz)
    endif
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Do you know some lightweight solutions? Is there any way just to modify the .vimrc file since plug-in may be inconvenient for switching platform/machine.